# XML won't show all tags inside tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Problem:

We have a XML document that shows alot of text. This text is wrapped inside -p-tags, and everything is wrapped inside a tag called -avsnitt-. However, only the first -p-tag in every -avsnitt- will show up.

XML code:

```
<seksjon>
<p>3.1. Introduction</p>
<avsnitt>
<p>SIMULA is a general purpose programming language. It inherits the algorithmic properties of ALGOL 60 and introduces methods for structuring data. The main characteristic of SIMULA is that it is easily modelled towards specialized problem areas, and hence can be used as a basis for Special Application Languages.</p>

<p>In this Standard the name SIMULA is considered synonymous with SIMULA 67. Although there exists a predecessor, SIMULA I, this latter language has achieved limited use. It is recommended that the language defined in this Standard be referred to as "Standard SIMULA".</p>

<p>SIMULA includes most of the ALGOL 60 language. Wherever ALGOL is used in this Standard it relates to the STANDARD ALGOL 60 definition (ISO 1538).</p>
</avsnitt>
</seksjon>
```

XSL code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="kapittel/seksjon">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="p"/></h2>
<br></br>
<xsl:value-of select="avsnitt/p"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is indeed the most compact. Just for completeness sake I'll offer a verbose solution often found when XML and stylesheets are getting more complex.

```
<xsl:template match="/parent-of-seksjons">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="seksjon"/> <!-- this was your xsl:for-each -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="seksjon">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  <!-- basically, filter the seksjon tag from output -->
</xsl:template>

<!-- (1) matches any p tag directly beneath seksjon -->
<xsl:template match="seksjon/p">
  <!-- it's bad practice to <br/> just for whitespace -->
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 2em"><xsl:value-of select="."/></h2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="avsnitt">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  <!-- again, filter the tag but keep it's children -->
</xsl:template>

<!-- (2) matches any p tag directly beneath avsnitt -->
<xsl:template match="avsnitt/p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- catch-all -->
<xsl:template match="@*|*" priority="-1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Btw, I wouldn't use `<seksjon><p>`  but `<seksjon title=".."/>` or even `<seksjon><title>` if possible.

If this is too verbose, you can just add template (1) and template (2) to your XSL and replace your `<xsl:value-of` with `<xsl:apply-templates`

Answer (score 3):

That is correct if you're using XSLT 1.0, because `value-of` when given a node set containing more than one node will return the string value of the *first* node in the set in document order.  You probably want to use `copy-of` instead of `value-of`, which will copy all the selected nodes to the result tree

```
<xsl:for-each select="kapittel/seksjon">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="p"/></h2>
<br></br>
<xsl:copy-of select="avsnitt/p"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This would produce output like

```
<h2>3.1. Introduction</h2>
<br />
<p>SIMULA is a general purpose programming language. It inherits the algorithmic properties of ALGOL 60 and introduces methods for structuring data. The main characteristic of SIMULA is that it is easily modelled towards specialized problem areas, and hence can be used as a basis for Special Application Languages.</p>
<p>In this Standard the name SIMULA is considered synonymous with SIMULA 67. Although there exists a predecessor, SIMULA I, this latter language has achieved limited use. It is recommended that the language defined in this Standard be referred to as "Standard SIMULA".</p>
<p>SIMULA includes most of the ALGOL 60 language. Wherever ALGOL is used in this Standard it relates to the STANDARD ALGOL 60 definition (ISO 1538).</p>
```